# How to keep track of retry count value from until-successful component (synchoronous mode) in mule 3?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am using mule version 3.9.
I am calling an REST API in a subflow. This sub flow is referenced inside until-successful component in main flow. I am using synchronous mode. I will retry 2 more times if I get Http response code as 503 or 404 from that API. I need to keep track of retry count and persist that value in DB.

***Solutions I tried:***

1.) I also tried using flow variable and session variable and increment it in the subflow. But it is not working because the variable is reset to original value for each retry.

2.) I am afraid to use registry to maintain count value as it is not thread safe and reading and writing into the registry map may cause issue.

Please let me know if there is any workaround to maintain retry count value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object store to save the count and make the key for it something unique to the message such as the correlationId.

Documentation:

- https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/The-Different-Types-of-Object-Stores-Explained
- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-object-stores
- https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store-connector/0.3.9/